# One to Many projections using Jpa QueryDSL Projections Bean

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

I'm using JPA with QueryDSL, In that scenario, I'm going to use JpaQuery Projections for fetching the only required data from DB. In my entity there is one OneToMany(List) Mapping But I'm not able to do projection on OneToMany mapping fields ie List. Please, anyone, tell me how we can get List by using projections in OneToMany mapping.

My entity class:-

```
public class Brand {
@Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = COLUMN_BRAND_ID)
    private int brandId;

    @Column(name = COLUMN_BRAND_NAME, columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(255)", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String brandName;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE )
    @JoinColumn(name = BRAND_LOGO_SMALL_FOREIGN_KEY)
    private File brandLogoSmall;

    @OneToOne(cascade =  CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinColumn(name = BRAND_LOGO_LARGE_FOREIGN_KEY)
    private File brandLogoLarge;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = COLUMN_CONTACT_PERSONS, nullable = true)
    private List<BrandContactPerson> contactPersons;

    @Column(name = COLUMN_OTHER_DETAILS, columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(255)", nullable = true)
    private String otherDetails;

    @Column(name = COLUMN_BRAND_STATUS, columnDefinition = "TINYINT(1) DEFAULT 1", nullable = false)
    private int status;

    @Column(name = BRAND_ADDED_BY_FOREIGN_KEY, nullable = true)
    private int createdBy;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = COLUMN_BRAND_ADDED_ON, columnDefinition = "DATETIME", nullable = false)
    private Date createdDate;

    @Column(name = BRAND_MODIFIED_BY_FOREIGN_KEY, nullable = true)
    private int updatedBy;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = COLUMN_BRAND_MODIFIED_ON, columnDefinition = "DATETIME", nullable = true)
    private Date updatedDate;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinColumn(name = COLUMN_CLASSIFICATION)
    private Classification classification;

//Setter Getter

}
```

Service Impl Class

```
@Repository
public class BrandCustomRepositoryImpl implements BrandCustomRepository {

    @Autowired
    private BrandQueryDslRepository brandQueryDslRepository;

    @Autowired
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public List<Brand> search(BrandSearchModel searchQuery) {

        JPAQuery<Contract> query = new JPAQuery<>(em);


        QBrand qBrand = QBrand.brand;

        BooleanBuilder builder = new BooleanBuilder();
        if (searchQuery.getPageNo() == null) {
            searchQuery.setPageNo(0);
        }
        if (searchQuery.getPageSize() == null) {
            searchQuery.setPageSize(UserSearchModel.DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE);
        }
        prepareBrandSearchBuilder(builder, qBrand, searchQuery);
        builder.and(qBrand.status.eq(Constant.ACTIVE));

        List<Brand> brand1 = query.from(qBrand.brand).where(builder).offset(0).limit(20)
                .select(Projections.bean(Brand.class, qBrand.brandName,qBrand.contactPersons))
                .fetch();



        return brand1;
    }
```

This is the above example. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What a the erro printed to you?

Comment: @HenriqueFernandesCipriano actully i m not getting error m not able to do projection on that list(onetomany)

Comment: And what does "I'm not able to do projection on OneToMany mapping fields" exactly mean?

Comment: @jannis I want to do projection on my entity class but when i am going to do it on OneToMany mapping list m not able to map it